# How to work out p-value if variances of two groups are different?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, t-test, p-value, experiment-design

How do I work out the p value if the variance of my control and experimental group are different? I can't do the t-test anymore. How do I work the p -value out, what method?
Also, my two groups are different amount of trials. The control has 25 values and the experimental only has 5 values. Hence I can't do the chi-squared test.

Comment: Welcome to CV. You are referring to two tests with very different hypotheses. What are you trying to demonstrate?

Answer (score 3):

As you are talking about the t-test, I assume that you want to compare the mean of the experimental and the control group. An 'extension' of Student's t-test to unequal sample sizes and unequal variances is [Welch's t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test). Welch's t-test uses the test statistic

$$  \frac{\overline{X}_1 - \overline{X}_2}{\sqrt{ \; {s_1^2 \over N_1} \; + \; {s_2^2 \over N_2}}}. $$

This test statistic is approximately t-distributed with $\nu$ degrees of freedom, with $\nu$ given by:

$$ {{\left( \; {s_1^2 \over N_1} \; + \; {s_2^2 \over N_2} \; \right)^2 } \over
 { \quad {s_1^4 \over N_1^2 (N_1-1)} \; + \; {s_2^4 \over N_2^2 (N_2-1) } \quad }} .$$

The p-value is then calculated using Student's t-distribution with $\nu$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: The degrees of freedom you present is Satterthwaite's formula. Welch's formula is $$df = -2 + \frac{\left(\frac{s_{x}^{2}}{n_{x}} + \frac{s_{y}^{2}}{n_{y}}\right)^{2}}{\frac{\left(s_{x}^{2}\right)^{2}}{n_{x}+1} + \frac{\left(s_{y}^{2}\right)^{2}}{n_{y}+1}}$$ Satterthwaite, F.  E.  1946.  An approximate distribution of estimates of variance components.  *Biometrics Bulletin* 2: 110-114. Welch, B.  L.  1947.  The generalization of “Student’s” problem when several different population variances are involved.  *Biometrika* 34: 28-35.

Comment: @Alexis Thank you. Wikipedia calls it the Satterthwaite-Welch formula.

Comment: Yes well, there's Wikipedia, then there's the *actual authors'* respective work cited. :)

Comment: Formulas from original papers sometimes get adjusted or refined in usage: Snedecor and Cochran (1980) and the [NIST handbook](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda353.htm) (current) both have 
 what looks to me like the same formula as Wikipedia. Would be the last to claim Wikipedia is always right, but maybe this time....

Answer (score 1):

When sample sizes are very different, as in your case, a problematic
situation occurs for the pooled two-sample t test if the population variance is larger in the
population from which we have the smaller sample size.

Let's look at an example in which we have 25 observations `x` from 
$\mathsf{Norm}(50, 2)$ and 5 observations `y` from $\mathsf{Norm}(60, 5),$
where the second argument in my notation for a normal distribution is the
population standard deviation.

Here are fake data, generated in R, and their stripcharts:

```
set.seed(915);  x = rnorm(25, 50, 2);  y = rnorm(5, 60, 5)
all = c(x,y);  gp = c(rep(1,25), rep(2,5))
stripchart(all ~ gp, ylim=c(.5, 2.6), pch="|")
```

[image]

In R, the default version of a two-sample t test is the Welch test:

```
t.test(all ~ gp)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  all by gp
t = -2.7021, df = 4.1464, p-value = 0.05195
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -14.43014179   0.09579794
sample estimates:
mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
       50.11499        57.28217
```

So at the 5% level, the difference in sample means (50.11 and 57.28) is not quite significantly different from $0.$ [The P-value for one-sided test against alternative $H_a: \mu_t < \mu_c$ would have been half as large, significant at the 5% level.]

The P-value for this two-sided test is found in R (where `pt` is the CDF of a t distribution) as follows:

```
2*pt(-2.7021, 4.1464)
[1] 0.05194632
```

Ordinarily, you need software to find an exact P-value. Taking df = 4, you can
bracket the P-value corresponding to $|T| = 2.7$ by using a printed table of t distributions: Noting that the probability in the right-hand tail of $\mathsf{T}(\nu=4)$ beyond 2.776 is 0.025, and that the probability beyond 2.131 is 0.05,
you can deduce that the P-value for the two-sided test is between 0.05 and 0.10.

With $n_1 = 25,\, n_2 = 5,$ the degrees of freedom $\nu$ from the formula given in
@Nussig's Answer (+1) must lie between $\min(n_1-1, n_2 - 1) = 4$ and $n_1 + n_2 - 2 = 28.$
In our example, we happen to be near the lowest possible value of $\nu.$ [Some software programs round to integer degrees of freedom.]

*Notes:* (1) An inadvisable pooled two-sample t test (with `t.test(all ~ gp, var.eq=T)`)
uses $\nu = n_1 + n_2 - 2$ along with a somewhat different formula for
the t statistic $(T = -5.298),$ giving the (bogus) 'highly significant' P-value `1.228e-05`.

(2) When
$n_1 = 25, n_2 = 5, \sigma_1 = 2, \sigma_2 = 5,$ a pooled two-sample t test
at 'advertised' significance level 5% has ***actual*** significance level above 25%.
The following simulation verifies this:

```
set.seed(918) 
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(25,0,2),rnorm(5,0,5),var.eq=T)$p.value)
mean(pv < .05)
[1] 0.26253
```

By contrast, the Welch two-sample t test has nearly the nominal 5% level:

```
set.seed(2018)
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(25,0,2),rnorm(5,0,5))$p.value)
mean(pv < .05)
[1] 0.05404
```